# Converting kubernetes kublet API usageNanoCore or usageCoreNanoSeconds to CPU utilization % Kubernetes kublet API

Tags: kubernetes, cpu-usage

I'm querying the Kubernetes kubelet API (curl -s http://localhost:10255/stats/summary) for CPU/Memory statistics and the CPU info is showing up as follows.

```
        "cpu": {
            "time": "2016-08-04T22:48:22Z",
            "usageNanoCores": 6392499,
            "usageCoreNanoSeconds": 3270519504746
        },
```

How do I convert usageNanoCores or usageCoreNanoSeconds to CPU utilization percentage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If a process were to run on one cpu continuously for a second, its
>   usage will be 1e+9 nanoseconds. If it ran on `n` cores continuously
>   its usage will n * 1e+9 nanoseconds.
>
> Percentage will be usage_in_nanoseconds / (capacity_in_absolute_cores
>   * 1e+9).

*source: https://github.com/kubernetes/heapster/issues/650#issuecomment-147795824